# Found shared references to a collection: OneToMany empty collections refering to same PersistentBag

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've the following model : An `Organization` has a `List<Contract>`, each `Contract` may have a `pricebookId` and a collection of `PricebookEntry`. Multiple `Contract` entities can have the same `pricebookId`. The `Collection<PricebookEntry>` is the result of a `@OneToMany` association with the `pricebookId` as `JoinColumn`.

Here is the postulate: **An organization has 2 contracts and both contracts have no `pricebookId`.**

And here is my problem: During an Hibernate session where this particular Organization is involved, Hibernate throws this exception:
`org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: Contract.pricebookEntries`.

Indeed, both contracts have their `pricebookEntries` set to the same `PersistentBag` (same reference).

How can I fix this ?

Thank you for your help!

```
@Entity
public class Organization implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private String id;

  @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "organization")
  private final List<Contract> contracts = new ArrayList<>();

}


@Entity
public class Contract implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "pricebook_id")
  private String pricebookId;

  @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Organization organization;

  @JoinColumn(name="pricebookId", referencedColumnName = "pricebook_id")
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
  private final Collection<PricebookEntry> pricebookEntries = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
public class PricebookEntry {

  @Id
  private String id;

  private String pricebookId;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here isn't a `@OneToMany` relationship, since multiple `Contract` entities may reference the same (set) of `PricebookEntry` instances.

To fix turn the `Collection<PricebookEntry>` into a proper entity `Pricebook` and have a many-to-one relationship from `Contract` to `Pricebook`. 
Also lose the now redundant `pricebookid` since it is simply the id of the `Pricebook`.